# EXC_BAD_ACCESS AppDelegate when use textview scroll method

Tags: ios, swift, exc-bad-access

I have a popover and when I am scrolling my textview and dismiss the popover I am getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS in app delegate.

**Code below for text view scroll**

```
func textViewDidBeginEditing(textView: UITextView) {
    var scrollPoint : CGPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, textView.frame.origin.y + 300)
    isFormInputChanged = true
    self.contentScrollView.setContentOffset(scrollPoint, animated: true)
}

func textViewDidEndEditing(textView: UITextView) {
    self.contentScrollView.setContentOffset(CGPointZero, animated: true)
}
```

**Code for dismiss the popover**

```
    if isFormInputChanged == true
    {
        var pagetitle = dict[constants.lable.WARNING_TITLE]
        var button1Title = dict[constants.lable.YES]
        var button2Title = dict[constants.lable.NO]
        var alertMessage = dict[constants.lable.alert.CANCEL_UNIT_SAVE_ALERT]
        customControllerWithCancelForm(pagetitle!, button1Title: button1Title!, button2Title: button2Title!, alertMessage: alertMessage!)
    }
    else
    {
        var tmpController :UIViewController! = self.presentingViewController
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: {()->Void in
            self.unitDetailProtocolVar!.closeUnitDetail()
        });
    }
```

Can someone please let me know what i am doing wronge?

Thanks,

Comment: does the crash happen on a specific line of that code?

Comment: Do you get an exception message? Have you tried setting an exception breakpoint

Comment: Read the Swift documentation until you understand the meaning of Optionals, and especially forced Optionals. Learn how to use Xcode, set breakpoints, and exception breakpoints. Not doing this is what you did wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing too much forced unwrapping. You should always do optional binding:

```
  if isFormInputChanged == true 
  {
    if let pagetitle = dict[constants.lable.WARNING_TITLE],
           button1Title = dict[constants.lable.YES],
           button2Title = dict[constants.lable.NO],
           alertMessage = dict[constants.lable.alert.CANCEL_UNIT_SAVE_ALERT] 
    {
        customControllerWithCancelForm(pagetitle, button1Title: button1Title, button2Title: button2Title, alertMessage: alertMessage)
    }
  }
  else 
  {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: { () -> Void in
      if let unitDetailProtocolVar = self.unitDetailProtocolVar {
        unitDetailProtocolVar.closeUnitDetail()
      }
    });
  }
```